# @HTML.CheckBoxFor() is not sending back value of unchecked boxes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

My code looks as below:

```
<div>
 <label>
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x.IsEnabled)
      IsEnabled</label>     
</div>
```

The problem is that CheckBoxFor is creating a hidden for this fields but still when the box is checked it is not sending the changed value to the server. I still get the value as true even if I uncheck it. This field appears inside a form, which I am not submitting using submit, but serializing (using jquery serializer) then submitting it.

The problem is that the serializer picks up the value property of every element and the checkbox value property is not changed in toggling. The property checked is the one which is changing.

Is there any way I can fix it??

Comment: Try this `@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsEnabled, new { @checked = "checked" })`

Comment: Can you post the jquery code that is submitting it.  Maybe your problem is there.  Also The controller code would help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in some cases there is no way to hack this with CheckBoxFor, but you can do:

`@Html.CheckBox("IsEnabled", Model.IsEnabled)`

Instead, and it should work better.
Checkboxfor creates some hidden variables with which it operates when submiting forms:

```
<input name="IsEnabled" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="IsEnabled" type="hidden" value="false">
```

This can be a problem for jquerish plugins. Especially the ones serializing stuff, since they probably do just simple property mapping.

Comment: well then, post what jquery serializer outputs then and more info :)

Answer (score 0):

When I use the normal Html input type binding the model by name. It works perfectly:

```
<label>
   <input id="IsEnabled" name="ISEnabled" type="checkbox" value="true" />
       IsEnabled
 </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active.Value)
```

i think this will help you.

Comment: This is not working for me. My checkbox is returning true value even if I unchecked it. Do you have any suggestions?